# Text vertical centered in sticky BootStrap footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have big problem with vertical center in BS footer. My code below :

```
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#">SITE1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SITE2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                <div class="center-inner">
                <p class="text-muted inner">Some text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                <p>More text.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4wLpk9h/1/)

Unfortunatelly, text in 2nd and 3th column isn't vertically centered. I tried solutions from similar topics, but sadly - without good effects in sticky footer (in most cases - it changed footer height and layout - after added display:table).

Below i uploaded graphic illustrating how it looks today, and how I would like it to look :
[image: preview]

Home somebody can help me with this.

Comment: bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: bootstrap 3, but i already got answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
.center-vertical{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

(just apply to parent boxes)

https://jsfiddle.net/kaskull/z4wLpk9h/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You can set the `media-query` value to set the break-point.

Check working updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z4wLpk9h/4/)

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li><a href="#">SITE1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SITE2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
        <div class="center-inner">
          <p class="text-muted inner">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
        <p>More text.</p>
      </div>


    </div>


  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}


}
footer [class*="col-"] p {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

```css
footer .text-muted.inner, footer p{padding:10px 15px;margin:0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#">SITE1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SITE2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                <div class="center-inner">
                <p class="text-muted inner">Some text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                <p>More text.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your links has a padding around it, so that you should also adding padding in `p` tag.

```
.footer [class*="col-"] p {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z4wLpk9h/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's really inventive.